# How to fix TypeError: Cannot set property 'financial.deposits' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongodb-query

I get an error TypeError: Cannot set property 'financial.deposits' of undefined when I want to push a value inside my financial.deposit which is field in my MongoDB collection users;

```
const query = {}; 

query["$push"]["financial.deposits"] = {
            hello: "hello"
     }      

 await UserModel.update({ _id: key }, query).exec();
```

I tried this but it is throwing me the exception.

Comment: can I show your users table data?

Comment: you mean show you

Comment: yes.. i want to check which you trying to update

Comment: I can't place a picture here, the field is an object type and have only one data which is  an object .

Comment: you can write this or simply post in comments

Comment: ok, the field is called financial it just under the password and email, this is all of it and it looks like that:  financial { deposits:{ }}; Deposits is an object just like financial

Comment: {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4976ac1f28f608707dba3c"),
    "financial" : {
        "deposite" : {
            "hello" : "hello"
        }
    }
}

Comment: is your data look like this?

Comment: yeah, the only difference is that the hello can't be set it throws the fault there

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be look like this:

```
const query = {$push:{"financial.deposite":{['key1']:"anything"}}};     

db.usertest.update({  "_id" : ObjectId("5d4976ac1f28f608707dba3c")}, query)
```

Comment: yes but this will delete the previous value set to the hello if I change it, the idea is the key will be different, I am sorry that doesn't show it in the code but the field needs to save all the different data which is give by an array : <br> if (deposits && deposits.data && deposits.data[key]) {
          query["$push"]["financial.deposits"] = {
            "$each": deposits.data[key]
          }
        }

Comment: then your financial deposite field is array..you said it  is object

Comment: ahh yeah I type it two times I meaned the financial and type it to it two times, I am sorry, yeah in the database it is an. array

Comment: I am sorry for this